# Error The MenuBar parameter must be a boolean when I am trying to open report

Tags: visual-studio, devexpress

I am started to work on a project with DevExpress 7.1.4 (old version 2007) and when I am trying to open the report I am getting the following error:
**The MenuBar parameter must be a boolean**

If someone had the same problem and how can it be solved? please, write about it. Thank you.

UPD: I found that 7.1.4 is not compatible with vs17, but I can't know any idea where I could open the report by 7.1.4

Call Stack:
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.UtilityMethods.CastTo[T](Object o, T defaultT, String exceptionMessage)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.Automation.CommandBars.AddArguments..ctor(Object name, Object position, Object menuBar, Object temporary, Object protection)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.Automation.CommandBars.AddEx(Object Name, Object Position, Object MenuBar, Object Temporary, Object Protection)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.Automation.CommandBars._Marshaler.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.b__0()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ThreadHelper.Invoke[TResult](Func`1 method)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.PlatformUI.Automation.CommandBars._Marshaler.Add(Object Name, Object Position, Object MenuBar, Object Temporary)
at DevExpress.XtraReports.Design.Commands.XRFormattingCommandBar.CreateCommandBar()
at DevExpress.XtraReports.Design.Commands.XRCommandBar.Initialize()
at DevExpress.XtraReports.Design.Commands.XRCommandBar..ctor(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, String name)
at DevExpress.XtraReports.Design.Commands.CommandBarFontService..ctor(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
at DevExpress.XtraReports.Design.Commands.ZoomCommandBarFontService..ctor(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
at DevExpress.XtraReports.Design.ReportFormattingBar..ctor(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
at DevExpress.XtraReports.Design._ReportDesigner.GetReportTool(IServiceProvider srvProvider)
at DevExpress.XtraReports.Design.ReportDesigner.Initialize(IComponent component)
at DevExpress.XtraReports.Design._ReportDesigner.Initialize(IComponent component)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.AddToContainerPostProcess(IComponent component, String name, IContainer containerToAddTo)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.PerformAdd(IComponent component, String name)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.DesignerHost.System.ComponentModel.Design.IDesignerHost.CreateComponent(Type componentType, String name)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.CreateInstance(Type type, ICollection arguments, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.DesignerSerializationManager.System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.IDesignerSerializationManager.CreateInstance(Type type, ICollection arguments, String name, Boolean addToContainer)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeTypeDeclaration declaration)
at DevExpress.XtraReports.Design.ReportCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, Object codeObject)
at System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization.CodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager manager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.PerformLoad(IDesignerSerializationManager serializationManager)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Design.Serialization.CodeDom.VSCodeDomDesignerLoader.DeferredLoadHandler.Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextManager.Interop.IVsTextBufferDataEvents.OnLoadCompleted(Int32 fReload)

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: @Brendon VS 17, and VS 2022 (same problem)

Comment: I found that 7.1.4 is not compatible with vs17, but I can't know any idea where I could open the report by 7.1.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you view the [Prerequisites documentation](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/8092/prerequisites), you will see that DevExpress v7.1.4 is only compatible with Visual Studio versions 2005 and 2008. You will need to either change to a newer version of the DevExpress XtraReports suite or use an older version of Visual Studio to work with your version.